# C# LINQ object reference not set

Tags: c#, linq

Considering the following code

```
IEnumerable<String> query = null;    
query = from x in xml.Descendants(xmlMasterContainerName).Descendants(xmlElementName)
                    let guid = x.Attribute("guid") ?? new XAttribute("guid", "-1")
                    where x.Attribute(xmlAttributeIdName).Value == xmlAttributeIdValue
                    select guid.Value;
```

I get the 'object reference not set' when trying query.ToList()

This is very probably caused by 'select guid.Value' when 'x.Attribute(xmlAttributeIdName).Value == xmlAttributeIdValue' does not exist.

How can I check the where statement for existing value before selecting?
Thanks

Comment: You can do `where /*object exists*/ && /* object is okay */`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XLinq, you usually don't use `Attribute().Value` directly, because of the exact error you are getting. Instead, you cast it. The cast will result in `null` if `Attribute()` returned null, so there will be no exception.

So, you would change your where clause to this:

```
where ((string)x.Attribute(xmlAttributeIdName)) == xmlAttributeIdValue
```

and your select to this:

```
select (string)guid
```

BTW: I would write that code like this:

```
var query = xml.Descendants(xmlMasterContainerName)
               .Descendants(xmlElementName)
               .Where(x => ((string)x.Attribute(xmlAttributeIdName)) ==
                               xmlAttributeIdValue)
               .Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("guid") ?? "-1");
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is no attribute `xmlAttributeIdName` you will get an exception accessing `Value` property. Use casting instead (it will return default value). Also you don't need to create attribute - you can simply return value:

```
IEnumerable<String> query = null;    
query = from x in xml.Descendants(xmlMasterContainerName)
                     .Descendants(xmlElementName)
        where (string)x.Attribute(xmlAttributeIdName) == xmlAttributeIdValue
        select (string)x.Attribute("guid") ?? "-1";
```